# Proper complements that may come after "jealous"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Is it correct to say that a husband is jealous to his wife? meaning that he always get jealous about her relationship with  male colleague...etc.

I was not able to find a right phrase to describe that.

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary? I looked up *jealous* in three, and all supplied the proper complement.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: I am searching for the proper complement for a specific situation which I explained above .And I searched Longman,Oxford,Collins,Cambridge and others .

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following examples:
- He's jealous of her (she has something that he doesn't and it makes him upset);
- He's jealous about/in regards to her (he wants to keep her to himself).

If you want a good alternative, you could say:
- "he's possessive about her", meaning he wants to keep her all to himself (take possession).

Comment: It would be good to allow OP to do their own basic research. [lingohelp.me/preposition after adjective/jealous of-about-for-by-in](https://lingohelp.me/preposition-after-adjective/jealous-of-about-for-by-in/) looks at the prepositions it is possible to use after 'jealous'. Here, OP's 'he [is] jealous about her relationship with male colleagues' can't be reduced to 'he is jealous Prep her'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, the site that you linked is amazing! Much friendlier than Ngrams for non-technical users. You should add that to the [Meta resource list](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available).

Comment: The meaning I am searching for is not "envy". If I say He is jealous about her wouldn't that mean that he is envious of her success (etc). I understand that "about" is used with "jealous" before the thing that causes jealousy for example :"There’s nothing for you to feel jealous about" .

Comment: then "possessive" in the 3rd example is better overall, that's all i can think of right now.

Comment: Yes. The link I posted seems a good reference, though I'm not saying people using it will always come to sound conclusions (and notice that corpora include misusages). But I can't see any of the alternatives << jealous PREP his wife >> giving the intended meaning. A arger structure, or the use of 'possessive', gives the intended meaning, but notice that the title question asks about colligates of 'jealous'.

Comment: Asking a native speaker (American) and explaining to him the meaning I need he said he did not know any direct way to say it. He said that if he needed to tell his wife or girlfriend that he was always jealous and she needed to behave in away that did not make him jealous, he would just say "I am a jealous man and you know it "